How does global variable gets updated here?
This question is not seeking a solution. But an explanation for the working solution.
The problem I had was to create a nested JSON where I get the hierarchy in a dot(.) separated formate.
example
Path: a.b.c.d
Value: 123
output should be
{
    "A": {
        "B": {
            "C": {
                "D": 123
            }
        }
    }
}

Now I do have a working solution for this
import 'dart:convert';

Map<String, dynamic> mainJson = {};

void main() {
  List<String> references = [
    'A.B.C.D1',
    'A.B1.C.D1',
    'A.B2.C.D3',
  ];
  for (var reference in references) {
    enterValueForReference(reference, '123');
  }
  print(jsonEncode(mainJson));
}

enterValueForReference(String reference, dynamic value) {
  List<String> nodes = reference.split(".").toList();
  List<String> parentNodes = nodes.sublist(0, nodes.length - 1);
  Map<String, dynamic> parentJson = {};
  Map<String, dynamic> lastJson = {nodes.last: value};
  parentJson = mainJson;
  for (var node in parentNodes) {
    if (parentJson.keys.contains(node) == false) {
      parentJson[node] = Map<String, dynamic>();
    }
    parentJson = parentJson[node];
  }
  parentJson.addAll(lastJson);
}

I just don't know how this is working. parentJson = mainJson; this creates a reference between parentJson and mainJson but, parentJson = parentJson[node]; this should update the mainJson as well, right?
If anyone can make sense of the code, that would be helpful.

"parentJson = mainJson; this creates a reference between parentJson and mainJson" No.  It makes parentJson store a reference to the same object that mainJson refers to.  You have two variables that refer to the same object. "parentJson = parentJson[node]; this should update the mainJson as well, right?" No.  It makes parentJson store a reference to another object.  It does not affect which object mainJson refers to.

@jamesdlin thanks for the response. But if you run the code you'll see that mainJson also updates with parentJson on line parentJson[node] = Map<String, dynamic>();

Reassignment is different than mutation. parentJson[node] = Map<String, dynamic>() mutates the object referred to by parentJson.  If mainJson and parentJson are referring to the same object, then when that object is mutated, both variables will continue referring to that same mutated object.

@jamesdlin I think I understood how this works now. mainJson and parentJson are referring to same object initially, But at the end of each iteration parentJson's reference will change to the value of the key we are iterating on.
